# Flask page wont redirect after registration form is validated

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-wtforms, flask-login

After the user registers on the register form, it should redirect them to the home page, but instead it doesn't do anything. It simply reloads the page without the user's password in the password fields.

This is home.py

```
` from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, flash, redirect
from forms import RegistrationForm, LoginForm
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '7364683972504ghfbeg7390'

posts = [
    {

     'author': 'Sam',
     'title': 'Blog Post 1', 
     'content': 'First post content',
     'date_posted': 'November 20, 2022',

     },

    {
    
    'author': 'Jake',
    'title': 'Blog Post 2', 
    'content': 'Second post content',
    'date_posted': 'November 23, 2022'

    }
    ]

@app.route("/home")
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template('home.html', posts=posts)

@app.route("/about")
def about():
    return render_template('about.html', posts=posts)


@app.route("/register", methods=['GET','POST'])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash(f'Account created for {form.username.data}!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('register.html', title='Register', form=form)

@app.route("/login")
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    return render_template('login.html', title='Login', form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

this is base.html.

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  
      <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.css') }}">
        {% if title %}
        <title> Flask Blog - {{ title }}</title>
        {% else %}
        <title>Flask Blog</title>
        {% endif %}
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="site-header">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark static-top">
              <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand mr-4" href="/"></a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggle" aria-controls="navbarToggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggle">
                  <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/about">About</a>
                  </div>
                  <!-- Navbar Right Side -->
                  <div class="navbar-nav">
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/login">Login</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/register">Register</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </nav>
          </header>
          <main role="main" class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-8">
                {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
                  {% if messages %}
                    {% for category, message in messages %}
                      <div class="alert alert-{{ category }}">
                      {{ message }}
                      </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                  {% endif %}
                {% endwith %}
                {% block content %}
                  
                  {% endblock %}
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="content-section">
                  <h3>Our Sidebar</h3>
                  <p class='text-muted'>You can put any information here you'd like.
                    <ul class="list-group">
                      <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Latest Posts</li>
                      <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Announcements</li>
                      <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Calendars</li>
                      <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">etc</li>
                    </ul>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </main>
       
        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>`
```

This is forms.py

```
`from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, Email, EqualTo

class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', 
                            validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=20)])
    email = StringField('Email',
                          validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])   

    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])     
    confirm_password = PasswordField('Confirm Password', 
                        validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('Password')])
    submit = SubmitField('Sign Up')

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('Email', 
                        validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])     
    remember = BooleanField('Remember Me')
    submit = SubmitField('Login')`
```

I'm not getting any problems on VSCode, not sure where I went wrong. I am a beginner to Flask. I'm currently following Corey Schafer's tutorial on YouTube. I want it to redirect to the homepage once the user has entered their ifnromation to register.

Answer (score 0):

> Hi,
>
> ```
> @app.route("/register", methods=['GET','POST'])
> def register():
>     form = RegistrationForm()
>     if form.validate_on_submit():
>         flash(f'Account created for {form.username.data}!', 'success')
>         return redirect(url_for('home'))
>     return render_template('register.html', title='Register', form=form)
> ```
>
> is apparently not being validated on submit for some reason. Therefore
> the redirect code is never triggered . The reason for this validation
> failure is most likely here:
>
> ```
> password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])     
> confirm_password = PasswordField('Confirm Password', 
>                     validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('Password')])
> ```
>
> according to documentations, `EqualTo` validator accepts two
> parameters `(fieldname, message=None)`. You are however providing non
> existing fieldname 'Password' (it's a label of a field, not a name)
> `EqualTo('Password')`. The working approach could be like this:
> `EqualTo('password')`.
>
> The partial code with a change applied.
>
> ```
> password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])     
> confirm_password = PasswordField('Confirm Password', 
>                     validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('password')])
> ```
>
> If you still be having validation issues, check official docs
> [here](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/validators/) and follow the example of
>
> ```
> class wtforms.validators.EqualTo(fieldname, message=None)
> ```
>
> where an actual working example of password fields validation is
> available.

Comment: your solution ended up solving the problem. Thank you. I am a bit confused however. Is it not required to include the second paramater of message?

Comment: In that case, please make my answer as a solution. The second parameter is included by default with a value None.